# using case when then

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following snippet:

```
COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN (a.FIRST_ORDER_DAY = b.ORDER_DAY) THEN a.CUSTOMER_ID END) AS new_customer
```

I want to replicate the exact same behavior as a select function instead of a count function. As I don't know the function well enough, I don't know how:

i.e. beforehand the result was "x new customers"

Now I want to have a result, which would be

```
new customers:
123 (customer ID)
234 (another customer iD)
```

and so on.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: How is your table defined? There is no `count()` in your snippet. Please show complete statements. More relevant information gives better answers.

Comment: What do you mean "but not as a count function"? Your example doesn't use `COUNT`...

Comment: @ChrisMoutray - I think the OP tried to copy and paste a snippet, but missed the `COUNT` part.  Which is why the CASE statement is enclosed in ().

Comment: *FAIL!* comes to mind :)

Comment: Some more information on the tables would be useful. I am wondering how you filter out older customers from the list.

Comment: hi all, sorry. the correct snipped is: COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN (a.FIRST_ORDER_DAY = b.ORDER_DAY) THEN a.CUSTOMER_ID END) AS new_customer

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you just want a list of the customer IDs that are new.

For that, you don't need a CASE statement at all...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.CustomerID
FROM
  ???
WHERE
  a.FIRST_ORDER_DAY = b.ORDER_DAY
```

`???` should be replaced with whatever joins you have *(but didn't include in your question)*.

Comment: Wouldn't that just pull every customer who has ordered something? Unless the table where orders are stored is cleaned up it seems like that would pull a lot of false positives.

Comment: hi all, sorry. the correct snipped is: COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN (a.FIRST_ORDER_DAY = b.ORDER_DAY) THEN a.CUSTOMER_ID END)  AS new_customer

Comment: @JoeW - It's a copy of the logic the OP provided. I presume `ORDER_DAY` relates to the most recent order only. Therefore, if that matches the `FIRST_ORDER_DAY`, then the most recent order is the first order and so the customer is new. But that's supposition. This code simply outputs the IDs that the OPs code is counting.

Comment: Hi JoeW, thank you. why cant i use the same logic as above? the issue is, that i also want to have existing customers (i.e. all which are not new). with the original snippet this was just two lines, now with your suggestion i dont know how to set this up in one query. and yes: order day is a unique order which therefore is most recent.

Comment: @user1820913 I was under the impression from your question that you only wanted new customers in your results.